# How to get values form arrayes of textboxes and push them to two-dimensional-array?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, textbox

I create a matrix the size depends on the user, I generate random numbers.
The question is how can I get all the values from the array of textboxes and write them to another array.
Or maybe there is a much more reasonable way? But the fact is that I need to be able to "walk" in rows and columns. Form for creating a matrix

```cs
public void gen__matrix()
{
    int row = Convert.ToInt32(txt_row.Text);
    int col = Convert.ToInt32(txt_col.Text);
    int[,] ar_matrix = new int[row, col];

    addTextBox(row, col, ar_matrix);
}
```

The TextBox matrix itself with values

[image: this]

```cs
public void addTextBox(int row, int col, int[,] ar_matrix)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            double rnd_val = rnd.Next(1, col + 1);
            TextBox textboxEdit = new TextBox();

            int pos_x_lb = 10;
            int pos_x_lb_step = 85;

            int pos_y_lb = 10;
            int pos_y_lb_step = 30;

            textboxEdit.Size = new Size(80, 20);
            textboxEdit.Name = Convert.ToString(row + i);
            textboxEdit.Text = Convert.ToString(Math.Round(rnd_val, 3));
            textboxEdit.Font = new Font(textboxEdit.Font.FontFamily, 12);
            textboxEdit.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;

            textboxEdit.Location = new Point(pos_x_lb + (j * pos_x_lb_step), pos_y_lb + (pos_y_lb_step * i));
            panel1.Controls.Add(textboxEdit);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you assign the `Name` property of your text boxes like `textboxEdit.Name = "t_" + i + "_" + j;`, you can get any text box by `(TextBox)panel1.Controls.Find("t_" + i + "_" + j);`

Comment: somethink like that or what 
            for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < col; i++)
                {
                    (TextBox)panel1.Controls.Find("t_" + i + "_" + j);
                }
            }
but i have an errror

Comment: https://prnt.sc/sgngco i cant get why i have an error

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to attach an event handler to the textChangedEvent. This would requires that you know the matrix you want to update beforehand.

```
textboxEdit.TextChanged += (o, e) =>
        {
            ar_matrix[i, j] = int.TryParse(textboxEdit.Text, out var num) ? num : ar_matrix[i, j];
        };
```

Another alternative could be to set the Tag property of each textbox

```
textboxEdit.Tag = (i, j);
```

and iterate over all textboxes with the tag property set:

```
foreach (var textBox in panel.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            if (textBox.Tag is ValueTuple<int, int> indices && 
                int.TryParse(textBox.Text, out var num))
            {
                ar_matrix[indices.Item1, indices.Item2] = num;
            }
        }
```

Disclaimer: All code is untested